# On submission, this form will not run the validation script

Tags: javascript

I have tried and tried and cannot figure out why when I submit this form it will not activate the javascript function Validate().

This is nearly an exact replica of another form with namely one change: I've added a textarea and removed some check boxes.

I could really use some help troubleshooting this thing...

```html
<div id="MainDivDomID">
    <h1>Send us a message</h1>

    <form id="contactForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate()">
        <input name="Source" type="hidden" value="web" />
        <input name="FormID" type="hidden" value="af3031b7-8f0e-433d-b116-6f10f0f231df" />

        <div class="halves">
            <input name="be9953c9-471c-42f4-a1cf-524f5b67fc38_First" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
            <input name="be9953c9-471c-42f4-a1cf-524f5b67fc38_Last" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>

        <div class="halves">
            <input maxlength="255" name="463a05a6-e700-462d-b43d-0ef5cb793f11" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" />
            <input name="eae1ba0e-a5b4-423b-985c-dc36a73c45c5" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
        </div>

        <textarea maxlength="255" name="b60680e4-3e46-43a5-b4e8-a21c6363ea0c" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

        <input name="CaptchaAnswer" type="text" placeholder="Please answer the math question..." />
        <img src="https://my.serviceautopilot.com/images/security-question.jpg" alt="" />

        <p>
            <button id="submitButtonText" class="et_pb_button et_pb_bg_layout_dark">Send Message</button>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

```js
function Validate() {
    var IsValidated = true;

    if (document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_First')[0].value.trim() == "") {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please fill out your first name.");
    }
    if (document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_Last')[0].value.trim() == "") {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please fill out your last name.");
    }
    var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    var email = document.getElementsByName('017b9b5e-5595-4b74-97a2-187f45400b34')[0].value;
    if (email == "" || re.test(email) != true) {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please fill in your email address.");
    }
    if (document.getElementsByName('4a6b6e47-2fac-4cb4-8ca0-e4a3db4c7fc0')[0].value.trim() == "") {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please fill in your phone number.");
    }
    if (document.getElementsByName('b60680e4-3e46-43a5-b4e8-a21c6363ea0c')[0].value.trim() == "") {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please fill in a message.");
    }
    if (document.getElementsByName('CaptchaAnswer')[0].value != "8") {
        IsValidated = false;
        alert("Please answer the math question.");
    }

    if (IsValidated == true) {
        document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
    } else {
        alert("Please fill out all fields.");
        return false;
    }
}

function CreateEntity() {
    document.getElementById("submitButtonText").value = "create";
    Validate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior using `e.preventDefault();` otherwise it will try to submit the form

```js
function Validate(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var IsValidated = true;

  if (document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_First')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill out your first name.");
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_Last')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill out your last name.");
  }
  var re = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  var email = document.getElementsByName('017b9b5e-5595-4b74-97a2-187f45400b34')[0].value;
  if (email == "" || re.test(email) != true) {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill in your email address.");
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('4a6b6e47-2fac-4cb4-8ca0-e4a3db4c7fc0')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill in your phone number.");
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('b60680e4-3e46-43a5-b4e8-a21c6363ea0c')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill in a message.");
  }
  if (document.getElementsByName('CaptchaAnswer')[0].value != "8") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please answer the math question.");
  }

  if (IsValidated == true) {
    document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
  } else {
    alert("Please fill out all fields.");
    return false;
  }
}

function CreateEntity() {
  document.getElementById("submitButtonText").value = "create";
  Validate();
}
```

```html
<div id="MainDivDomID">
  <h1>Send us a message</h1>

  <form id="contactForm" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate(event)">
    <input name="Source" type="hidden" value="web" />
    <input name="FormID" type="hidden" value="af3031b7-8f0e-433d-b116-6f10f0f231df" />

    <div class="halves">
      <input name="be9953c9-471c-42f4-a1cf-524f5b67fc38_First" type="text" value="" placeholder="First Name" />
      <input name="be9953c9-471c-42f4-a1cf-524f5b67fc38_Last" type="text" value="" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="halves">
      <input maxlength="255" name="463a05a6-e700-462d-b43d-0ef5cb793f11" type="text" value="" placeholder="Email" />
      <input name="eae1ba0e-a5b4-423b-985c-dc36a73c45c5" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" />
    </div>

    <textarea maxlength="255" name="b60680e4-3e46-43a5-b4e8-a21c6363ea0c" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

    <input name="CaptchaAnswer" type="text" placeholder="Please answer the math question..." />
    <img src="https://my.serviceautopilot.com/images/security-question.jpg" alt="" />

    <p>
      <button type='submit' id="submitButtonText" class="et_pb_button et_pb_bg_layout_dark">Send Message</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an exception at the line of code

```
document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_First')[0].value.trim() == ""
```

Dont have any name a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_First in your document, so that the [0] is undefined.

If you change from

```
if (document.getElementsByName('a7aa41d9-b309-48d7-af97-5a2ce65eb850_First')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill out your first name.");
  }
```

to

```
 if (document.getElementsByName('be9953c9-471c-42f4-a1cf-524f5b67fc38_First')[0].value.trim() == "") {
    IsValidated = false;
    alert("Please fill out your first name.");
  }
```

The message Please fill out your first name will shown.